# Add Href's Of one list to a second list as ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 lists, one is a list of headings, and the second consist of the same headings with texts under the headings, I would like to link the first list to the second so when you press a heading in the first list it will jump you to the second list relative title.

```
<div class="links_categories">
      <a href="#item1">item1</p>
      <a href="#item2">item2</p>
      <a href="#item3">item3</p>
      <a href="#item4">item4</p>
</div>
```

And the second list is

```
<div class="links_categories">
      <p>item1</p>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
      <p>item2</p>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
      <p>item3</p>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
      <p>item4</p>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
         <div>item</div>
</div>
```

I managed to get all the href names from the first list to an array and now I trying to add them as ID's to the second list Items,

```
links = $('.links_categories a').map(function(){
return $(this).attr("href")});
```

How can this be done, or is there a smarter way of doing this ??

Comment: What is real you want to do??please clearify your need

Comment: I want to take the href from the first list and add them as ID's to the second list, the 2 lists has the same titles names.

Comment: Why do you close your links with paragraph tags? `<a>item1</p>`

Comment: which element of second list you wish to append...to <p> tag or a <div> tag??

Answer (score 0):

The following code will assign the link's text as its ID

```
$('a:contains("item")').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('id', this.innerHTML)
})
```

Comment: Great, so the question is, how can I take the values that are returned from the first function and pass them as the item/items for the second function